# Scaling an image being imported via a database

Tags: php, css, image, resize

I am working on a database project and have hit a cosmetic snag.

I have a database that loads profiles into arrays for displaying using a php while loop, so it is set to display the content of a database and allow for adding with no additional coding.

Four of the fields are picture upload locations, as part of the upload process is the ability to upload up to 4 different images, which are then saved in a directory and their path saved to the profile database.

Here is my problem however, not all the images are the same size (as in width and height). I have my code set up designating a specific area to an image to stop it filling up the screen, but rather then scale it, the code simply squishes or stretches the dimensions. So a 80*120 image being resized is just being distorted.

This is the section of code responsible for calling the image into the field.

```
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:<?php echo $imagepix ?    >;width:100px;height:120px;z-index:5;text-align:left;">

<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;"><img src="uploads/<?php     echo $productpicture ?>" alt="" style="width:70px;height:120px;" ></span></div>
```

The first section is a cosmetic alignment of the container, the second imports the image and formats it accordingly.

I am using the style= section for sizing but its obviously the wrong approach and I cant find any useful info on what exactly I'm looking for as half the battle is knowing what to ask!

The end result is to be able to scale an image so various requirements by simply changing a ratio on the output field such as altering style to style="width:140px;height:240px

I hope this makes sense and someone has some insight.

Thanks

Comment: Let me try to understand what you're trying to say.... You want to resize the image to fit your container, but you want it to keep the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use max-height and max-width instead of height and width, and apply a black background to the image container. You would also have to center the image in the container both horizontally and vertically. Do this by setting the line-height of the container equal to the height and using text-align.

```
<div id="image-container" style="width: 70px; height: 120px; text-align: center; line-height: 120px; background: black;">
    <img src="image.jpeg" style="max-height:120px; max-width: 70px; display: inline-block;" />
</div>
```

Of course you should put the style tags into a stylesheet instead.

If you would rather crop the image instead of having it fit in with a black background, let me know because this can also be done with CSS and maybe a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: Your a star! soon as I changed it to max-height etc all the pictures resized themselves and it no longer looks like a fun house of mirrors!

Thankyou.